# searching through text files for specific line c++

Tags: c++, file, search, text

So I have a txt file and I want to create a function to search through it and find a specific line. The txt file is a list of baby names and the frequency of the name being used. It looks like this:

```
jack,M,1456
julie,F,879
conner,M,540
ben,M,20843
```

Basically I want to have a function that will display the line of the name if the user inputs that name. So the user would be prompted to input a name, and I would use their input to search through the file until it finds the name. If julie were inputted by the user, the result would be the screen printing out julie,F,879.

Also, on that note, what if I had more than one txt file? For example:

```
file1.txt
jack,M,1456
julie,F,879
conner,M,540
ben,M,20843

file2.txt
jacob,M,15687
alex,F,5648
shannon,F,964
conner,M,760
```

How would I search through multiple txt files to find the line? If the user entered alex how would I get the function to search through two separate txt files?

And lastly (I know, this is dragging on..) If the user inputted conner, how would I get the program to display the lines from both txt files?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: A big what have you tried is in order.

Comment: I've tried looking up how to do this.. and haven't found anything useful

Comment: @userboss22 Programming is all about putting together familiar tasks (reading a file, comparing strings) in novel ways. I'm guessing you are struggling with that part. But I'm afraid you have to figure that out for yourself. You're not going to find tutorials on your exact problem, you have to find something close and then apply that to your situation.

Answer (score -1):

Just to give you a hint to start. You could use the stl [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) class, where you can also extract formatted data. The stl gives you a lot of means to achieve what you want.